# Radcombobox selectedindexchanged not firing on the javascript popup in RadAjaxPanel

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

I have used radcombobox on javascript pop up on selection of first combobox, I want to bind another combobox. but selectedindexchanged  event is not working and selection also get refreshed.

Here is my code,

```
<div id="basic-modal-content">
          <telerik:RadAjaxPanel runat="server" ID="RadAjaxPanel1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" EnableAJAX="true">
        <div class="basic_modal_form">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label>Market:</label>
                        <div class="basic_modal_form_cnt">
                            <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server"  ID="ddlMarkets_Compose" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMarkets_Compose_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Skin="MetroTouch" EnableEmbeddedSkins="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true"  EmptyMessage="Markets" Width="115" MaxHeight="300" DropDownAutoWidth="Enabled" CheckedItemsTexts="DisplayAllInInput">

                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </div>
                        <label>Vendor Name:</label>
                        <div class="basic_modal_form_cnt">
                            <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="ddlVendors_Compose" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlVendors_Compose_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Skin="MetroTouch" EnableEmbeddedSkins="true"  AppendDataBoundItems="true"  EmptyMessage="Vendors" Width="115" MaxHeight="300" DropDownAutoWidth="Enabled" CheckedItemsTexts="DisplayAllInInput">
                                <Localization CheckAllString="All Vendors" />
                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
    </div>
```

Please help me.....